# Get first result from google search and its URL's with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, discord.js

I have a piece of code that returns a URL with the search;

```
        if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "google")) {
        var lookup = message.content.replace(";google ", '');
        var newlookup = "https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=mFopW5aMIomSsAfRw77IDg&q=test";
        newlookup = newlookup.replace('test',lookup);
        newlookup = newlookup.replace(/\s+/g, '+')
        message.channel.send("<a:googling:426453223310622740>" + " Loading...").then(r => {
             setTimeout(function(){
                r.edit(newlookup);
            }, 2000);
            });
    }
```

But what i want is to return the URL of the first result i get. for example if i search "stackoverflow" i get "https://stackoverflow.com/"
im not sure how to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

Require it and then your code should be like this:

```
const google = require("google");
//..................................................................................
message.channel.send("<a:googling:426453223310622740> Loading...").then(msg => {
  google(lookup, (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    else {
      let url = res.links[res.start].link; //you can also use .href instead of .link
      msg.edit(url);
    }
  });
});
```

This way is simple, but at the same time is not the "right" one: this package is not supported by Google, and they could block your searches if you abuse it. That's all I could find.

Another way is to use the Google Search API, as suggested by André, but that would require you to create a custom search engine, and you won't be able to browse google itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as i know, there's no workaround for that :\